# Inclusion in the open interval

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $A=[3,4]$ and $B=[3,4)$ be two different intervals . 
Now $B$ contains the numbers $3.9,\ 3.99,\ 3.999,\ 3.9999$, and so on and there cannot be an end to it. Hence we can conclude B contains the number $3$.infinite repetition of $9$.
Now the number $3$.infinite repetition of $9$ is
noted as $3.\overline{9}$ or $3.999...$

Now $0.333...$ , $3.9999...$ all are rational numbers and hence they have their $p/q$ form.
Let $$0.333... = x \qquad (1)$$
From which we find
$$3.333....=10x\qquad (2)$$
Then by taking $(2)-(1)$ we find
$$3=9x\Leftrightarrow x=1/3 \Leftrightarrow 0.333... = 1/3$$
Similarly 
$$3.999... = x\Leftrightarrow 39.999... = 10x\Leftrightarrow36 = 9x\Leftrightarrow x = 4.$$
So $B$ which contains $3.9999...$ contains $4$ as $3.9999...= 4$
So $[3,4)=B = [3,4]$
Which is wrong according to real Analysis. Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are right when you assert that $[3,4)$ contains every number of the form$$3.\overbrace{999\ldots9}^{n\text{ times}},$$but it doesn't follow from this that $3.999\ldots\in[3,4)$. The set $[3,4)$ is the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $3\leqslant x<4$, and $3.999\ldots=4$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the limit of the series $3,99....$ is not included in the open interval. While for every $1\geq\varepsilon>0\ (4-\varepsilon)$ is included but $\varepsilon$ has to be strictly greater than 0, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be any subset of the real line (in fact of any topological space, but never mind).

Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence in $A$. If the limit point $s=\lim s_n$ exists, then $s$ must belong to the closure of $A$.

If $A$ is closed, then its closure is $A$. But if $A$ is not closed then its closure is strictly bigger than $A$.

The closure of a set is closed, and in fact it is the smallest closed set including the given set.

Just as a reminder: a subset is closed (by definition) if its complementary set is open. A subset $X$ of the real line is open if given any $x\in X$ there is an open interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ fully contained in $X$.

The interval $[3,4]$ is closed, but the interval $[3,4)$ is not (check this using the above definition).

Answer (score 0):

Everything in this is correct EXCEPT the sentence "Hence we can conclude B contains the number 3.Infinite repetition of 9". That is false. Just because it includes all the finite analogs does not mean it includes the limiting case. Think carefully about why you think the statement you made follows from the previous ones, and hopefully it should become clear that it does not follow!